# mySQL self join elegantly

Tags: mysql, sql

My question is a bit dummy, but SQL has never been my cup of tea. 
I have a simple table with 3 columns: `id, name, parent_id` (referring to an id in the same table).

I just want to get the relevant results to display them in an HTML page: 
ID / Name / Parent Name

I can query as follows:

```
select id, name, parent_id from fields
union
select a.id, a.name, b.name
from fields a, fields b
where b.parent_id = a.id;
```

and do some tests, but i can figure out that it exists some more elegant manner.

Thx.

Comment: Please Post code you have tried.Then i can help you to correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query is best achieved by using a `LEFT JOIN`. This way you can still return fields which do not have a `parent_id`, i.e. are `NULL`. You'll also want to select the `parent_name` using an alias (`parent_name` in the example). This will allow you to programatically refer to the result by it's name rather than the numerical column index (`$row->parent_name` vs `$row[2]` if PHP is your language of choice).

```
SELECT f1.id, f1.name, f2.name parent_name
FROM fields f1
LEFT JOIN fields f2 ON f2.id = f1.parent_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9632/1/0

Comment: +1 for the `LEFT JOIN`. The OP already has 3 different column aliases in his original query  (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.id AS ID, A.name AS Name, B.name AS Parent
FROM fields A, fields B
WHERE A.parent_id = B.id
```